# bpf_xdp_adjust_meta() returns errcode -13 (permission denied)

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, bpf, ebpf, xdp-bpf

### Problem:

`bpf_xdp_adjust_meta(ctx, -delta);` is returning error code -13 (permission denied) when delta > 32.
But [BPF and XDP Reference Guide](https://docs.cilium.io/en/stable/bpf/#xdp) states that there are 256 bytes headroom for metadata.
So did I misunderstand something or how can I use 256 bytes for metadata?

### Program:

```c
int xdp_prog_simple(struct xdp_md *ctx)
{   
    bpf_printk("---BPF DEBUG--- adjust_meta: %d\n", bpf_xdp_adjust_meta(ctx, -36));
    return XDP_PASS;
}
```

### Setup:

**Kernel:**
`uname -rv`
`5.8.0-63-generic #71-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 13 15:59:12 UTC 2021`
**Device:**
veth from [xdp-tutorial/testenv](https://github.com/xdp-project/xdp-tutorial/tree/master/testenv), because my hardware driver don't support native xdp mode.
**Loaded with:**

- `ip link set dev test xdp obj xdp_pass_kern.o sec xdp` and checked that the program is attached in xdp native mode.
- `bpf_set_link_xdp_fd()` from userspace program

I also tried to use **different compilation environments** (with their default `Makefile`):

1. [linux/samples/bpf](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/samples/bpf)
2. [xdp-tutorial/basic01](https://github.com/xdp-project/xdp-tutorial/tree/master/basic01-xdp-pass)

### Background:

I'm trying to pass data via the `xdp_md->data_meta` field to make the data accessible for tail-called eBPF programs. To adjust the data_meta pointer I call the eBPF helper function `bpf_xdp_adjust_meta(ctx, -delta);` where delta is the size of the struct holding the metadata.
This is working fine, as long as delta is <= 32. If it's bigger, the helper function returns -13 (Permission denied). That's why I guess that the headroom for metadata is 32 bytes in my case instead of 256 bytes as stated in [BPF and XDP Reference Guide](https://docs.cilium.io/en/stable/bpf/#xdp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum room space for metadata **is only 32 bytes**, so what you observe is expected.

You can check this by reading [the relevant kernel code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.13/source/net/core/filter.c#L3905), or [the logs for the commit that introduced the feature](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=de8f3a83b0a0fddb2cf56e7a718127e9619ea3da).

The documentation that you cited refers to the room size for encapsulation headers that you can modify with `bpf_xdp_adjust_head()`, not to the size for metadata. Admittedly it's not clear from the text (but PRs are welcome!).

Comment: Really helpful answer. Those two links were exactly what I needed. Thank you.
Now I saw that I should have had a look at the [implementation section](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/bpf-helpers.7.html#IMPLEMENTATION) to at least see how the helper is implemented.